# Why is removing subviews from superview in Objective-C creating memory leaks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiview, memory-leaks

I have a category for `UIView` which contains this method to remove all of its `subviews`:

```
- (void)empty {

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

and upon profiling my project I see multiple *memory leaks* all pointing to this code:

```
[wrapperView empty];
```

which in turn calls the first method.

I searched on Google and found out a cleaner and better solution using:

```
[self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

which doesn't create *memory leaks*.

My question is, why is the old solution creating memory leaks? Aren't the `UIView *subview`s released at the end of the `for` loop?

Comment: The `makeObjectsPerformSelector` does exactly the same as your first approach. This can be an issue with `Profiler` tool itself or you have leaks somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I don't think so, the stack traces were pointing to this exact code and after making the change no leaks were happening again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method you are mutating the array while iterating through it, in the second you are just sending a message to each object in the array.

To see this for yourself, replace the first method with

```
NSArray *subviews = self.subviews.copy;
for (UIView *view in subviews) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This way you are working on a copy of the subviews array.

Comment: The weird thing is that it works, and successfully removes all of the subviews.

Comment: Nothing weird about it. The subviews array on a view is a reference, and as you remove subviews, the array is changing. There is a general recommendation in Objective-C that you shouldn't mutate an array while you are iterating through it. By taking a copy, this is no longer the case.

Comment: I thought that by doing this it should get delayed until it crashes

Comment: The app. But that applies to a classic `for` with an `index`. So ignore the comments, I understood now, thanks.